# AES Encryption Different Result Java And Python

Tags: java, python, android, encryption, aes

I have this android java AES encryption code that make my token, now i want to make it in python too, but some how it has different result.

java

```
private Void encrypt(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, ShortBufferException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {

    byte[] bytes = password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
    .digest("mysecretkey".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)), "AES");

    Cipher instance = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    instance.init(1, secretKeySpec);

    byte[] bArr = new byte[instance.getOutputSize(bytes.length)];

    instance.doFinal(bArr, instance.update(bytes,0,bytes.length, bArr, 0));


    for (byte b : bArr){

        Log.d("encrypt", String.valueOf(b));

    }
}
```

python

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

import hashlib


def pad(byte_array):
    BLOCK_SIZE = 16
    pad_len = BLOCK_SIZE - len(byte_array) % BLOCK_SIZE
    return byte_array + (bytes([pad_len]) * pad_len)


def encrypt(key, message):


    byte_array = message.encode("UTF-8")
    panjang = len(message)

    padded = pad(byte_array)

    cipher = AES.new(key.encode("UTF-8"), AES.MODE_ECB)
    encrypted = cipher.encrypt(padded)

    for b in encrypted:
        print(b)





password = "mypassword"

secret_key = "mysecretkey"
hashkey = hashlib.md5(secret_key.encode()).hexdigest()

encrypt(hashkey,password)
```

java result

```
-25 -16 84 -36 100 -102 74 -98 -91 -77 100 -96 -86 28 -47 -67
```

python result

```
220 127 95 142 45 102 9 79 170 82 165 2 63 39 196 7
```

i've been figuring out this for days but cant see where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actually correct values your going for, i.e. encrypting a (padded) block with "mypassword" with the AES-key  MD5("mysecretkey"), this is

`e7 f0 54 dc 64 9a 4a 9e a5 b3 64 a0 aa 1c d1 bd`

viewed as hex. (produced with the standard `openssl` command line tool)

The Java code actually shows the correct result: if the above is in a file `p.enc` (as it is on my PC), I can display it in signed bytes as

`od -An -t d1 p.enc` and then I get

`-25 -16  84 -36 100 -102 74 -98 -91 -77 100 -96 -86  28 -47 -67`

which is your representation as well.

In Python you wrongly use `.hexdigest()` instead of `digest()`.

`hexdigest` produces a 32 character string (with ASCII values, not raw binary) so your AES.new call gets a 256-bits key, not 128 bits and the result will be wrong (you'll use AES-256)

You're not specifying what version of Python you're using.
But in Python (2.7) you can reproduce the correct result (assuming your same imports from Crypto and hashlib) as

`key=hashlib.md5('mysecretkey').digest()
 plain='mypassword'+ '\006'*6 #manual padding addition for the example
 aes=AES.new(key, AES.AES_ECB)
 cipher=aes.encrypt(plain)`

which gets the abovementioned correct value.

To view it in signed bytes (as Java does) for comparison's sake:

`[ord(b)-256 if ord(b)>127 else ord(b) for b in cipher]`

And the results then match up.

Answer (score 2):

You have different code structure, that makes it difficult to compare the examples. There's a `message` in your Python code, but not in your Java code.

My first guess is that you should be calling `digest` instead of `hexdigest` in the Python code.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html

You're doing conversions from hashes to strings to binary data, some of the latter with UTF-8, but one without. I recommend that you print and compare the actual values that you're passing to the encryption function in both languages.